# How does the new Drools 6.x KIE API work?

Tags: drools

I'm trying to upgrade from Drools 5.x to 6.x and to keep things as simple as possible. The new `kie` APIs are making this simple task difficult.

After many attempts, I managed to convert the standard Drools 5.x example into the 6.x equivalent. Notice that I purposely avoided XML configuration files, dependency injection, etc. but I still don't understand some passages.

I'm including both versions of the application to possibly help other people who has facing the same problem I had.

The following code is more or less what we were used to do in Drools 5.x:

```
// Obtain a builder for knowledge base
KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

// Load a DRL resource from src/main/resources into the builder
String location = "/drools/HelloWorld.drl";
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(location);
Resource resource = ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(stream);
builder.add(resource, ResourceType.DRL);

// Check for errors, print them and stop if any
if (builder.hasErrors()) {
    for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : builder.getErrors()) {
        System.out.println(error);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}

// Create a new knowledge base out of the builder
KnowledgeBase base = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
base.addKnowledgePackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());

// Start a new working session
StatefulKnowledgeSession session = base.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

// Inject a new message object into the session
final Message message = new Message();
message.setMessage("Hello World");
message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
session.insert(message);

// Apply the rules in the knowledge base to the objects in the session
session.fireAllRules();

// Close the working session
session.dispose();
```

Since Drools 6.x, `KnowledgeBase` has been deprecated so it will probably phase out of the codebase in the near future, forcing to use the new APIs. The above example in Drools 6.x becomes:

```
// Get access to Drools services
KieServices services = KieServices.Factory.get();

// Obtain a new empty virtual file system
KieFileSystem fileSystem = services.newKieFileSystem();

// Load a DRL resource from src/main/resources into the virtual file system
// The prefix 'src/main/resources' is required since Drools 6.2.x
String location = "/drools/HelloWorld.drl";
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(location);
Resource resource = ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(stream);
fileSystem.write("src/main/resources" + location, resource);

// Convert the files in the virtual file system into a builder
KieBuilder builder = services.newKieBuilder(fileSystem).buildAll();

// Check for errors, print them and stop if any
Results results = builder.getResults();
if (results.hasMessages(ERROR)) {
    System.out.println(results.getMessages());
    System.exit(0);
}

// Create a new kie base out of a repository and a container
KieRepository repository = services.getRepository(); // <---= HERE!
KieContainer container = services.newKieContainer(repository.getDefaultReleaseId());
KieBase base = container.getKieBase();

// Start a new working session
KieSession session = base.newKieSession();

// Inject a new message object into the session
final Message message = new Message();
message.setMessage("Hello World");
message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
session.insert(message);

// Apply the rules in the kie base to the objects in the session
session.fireAllRules();

// Close the working session
session.dispose();
```

I think that these new APIS are too verbose and a bit obscure to understand. I know that one of the reasons behind them is to allow an easier management of the rule bases (i.e.: packages) but the implementation is a bit convoluted and fails to do justice to the tool (i.e.: adoption is harder).

I know that using xml configuration files or dependency injection makes the code much simpler, however the former breaks the flow and the latter forces the inclusion of (many) more dependencies. Moreover, in either cases it becomes even more difficult to understand what is going on.

However, going back to the question, notice the line in the second snippet where the `KieRepository` is introduced:

```
KieRepository repository = services.getRepository(); // <---= HERE!
```

The `services` returns a `KieRepository` whose default release id is used to initialise a `KieContainer`. This container produces a `KieBase` that creates `KieSession`s when needed. **Notice that the previously initialised `KieBuilder` that contains the file system with the DRL file is not used anywhere to get the `KieBase`.** *How the `KieBase` knows about the DRL file? Through some side-effect in `KieServices`? If so, isn't this bad?*

Thanks in advance for any idea or explanation that you may have.

Comment: There is nothing to answer here: you've put it all down very nicely in your question! And I'm inclined to agree with you that this inherent relationship of some Builder working on a FileSystem and a Container created with some Repository ReleaseId and begetting a KieBase (which must be what the Builder has concocted) is absolutely baffling. I've been through the Drools documentation, and it simply fails to explain the *connections* between these entities - it's just describing the properties of each entity, from which you are supposed to deduce the essentials.

Comment: @laune I'm happy to see that you share my opinion! To be honest, the Drools documentation has never been remembered for being accurate and exhaustive (at least since v4.3, the first I've used). I've just stumbled upon Easy Rules (http://www.easyrules.org) which might be stupid (i.e.: lacking RETE/OO, PHREAK) but much more compact and without frills! I like it even though the way in which rules and beta-nodes are dealt is not optimised.

Comment: Actually EasyRules is not functionally comparable to a full fledged Production Rules System, but one of its ports - MintRules (https://github.com/augusto/MintRules) - is promising.

Answer (score 0):

Stefano, if you are only interested in load a bunch of drl in your application and you are not worried about KieContainers, Maven artifacts or the KieScanner, you could use the [KieHelper](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-knowledge/blob/master/kie-internal/src/main/java/org/kie/internal/utils/KieHelper.java) class.

For more information, check [my answer to this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32608363/1168802).

The only drawback here is that the KieHelper is not part of the Drools' public API.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Hi Esteban, it's nice to read from you again!
Thanks, the helper class is really simplifying the code, but it still doesn't help to understand what is going on under the hood...
Anyway, is the `KieHelper` allowing to add rules to a session at runtime?
(See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502310/how-to-dynamically-change-the-rules-of-a-given-drools-6-3-session)

Comment: Hi Stefano. No, if you want to modify your KieBases in runtime ,you may want to take a look at the `KieScanner` class in Drools 6.x.