# How to integrate Rule template with Drools Kie

Tags: java, github, drools, rule-engine

I am completely new to Drools Rule engine which is used in my organization application. The Drools rule engine that has been used in my application is 5.5.0 and we need to migrate it to Drools 6x.

I have referred to documentation and also [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592615/deprecated-code-of-drools-to-version-6-2) which highlights the usage.

In my application we use Rule Template and decision table. In the examples and documentation, it is mentioned that we need to create "kmodule.xml" file where we need to specify the package where the Rule DRL file is placed.
But in template based approach, the DRL file is not available until it is compiled against data set.

How can we then use Rule Template with Drools 6x? If any sample example or github sample project is present, it would really help.

Comment: You can use the API to compile a DRL without fiddling with any XML files. So you can generate the DRL and then store it in the KieFileSystem and build.

Comment: Could you please suggest an example. I am completely new to Drools.