# Creating multiple KieBase and creating the kmodule programmatically in drools

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I have in drools multiple packages for rules, each package contain different rules and I added all of the packages' rules to the kmodule.xml file, and once I run one of my bpmns (each package of rules has a different bpmn and ruleflow-grouo) all the rules get fired even the ones in different packages and different ruleflow-group. I want to create multiple Kiebase each one containing the relevant drl files (also building the kmodule programmatically and dynamically and not by writing them in the meta-inf folder) and once I decide which one I need, I will add the kiebase to the session and run the correct bpmn.  How can I implement this?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592615/deprecated-code-of-drools-to-version-6-2/32608363#32608363). There you can find 2 ways to programmatically create KieBases in Java.

Hope it helps,

Comment: My drl isn't running that way ( no exception) . Do you know how can I create the kmodule.xml dynamically in run-time and without using the default one placed in META-INF folder?

Comment: You can programmatically create `KieBases` using the `KieHelper` class shown in the thread I pointed to. I'm not sure what you mean by "my drl isn't running that way"...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this snippet can inspire you to hack it your way:

```
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

    String someRules = getRulesFromSomewhere(); // find your rules text here...

    kbuilder.add(someRules, ResourceType.DRL);


    if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
        //in case of compiling errors
        for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : kbuilder.getErrors()) {
            LOG.error(error.toString());
        }
    }else{

        kSession = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase().newStatelessKieSession();

        //use your stateless ksession here!
    }
```

In my case those "someRules" comes from a database query that get all rules from one table according to a certain criteria. You can easily use this kind of code to create multiple kieSessions based on different sets os rules.